# Not able to create merchant sandbox account for google wallet api for digital goods

Tags: android-pay

I am trying to integrate my django web app with google wallet api for digital goods to handle payments. I am using this tutorial: https://developers.google.com/wallet/digital/docs/tutorial

For creating sandbox merchant account for seller, I click on https://sandbox.google.com/checkout/inapp/merchant/signup.html.
After filling the form and click on submit button I am getting the error message:

> There was an error completing sign-up. Learn more

I am not able to generate merchant ID or key.